# doctrine flush updates don't sync to Factory-created object in KernelTestCase

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit, fixtures

I have a test for a service method `NewsletterService::unsubscribe`. I am trying to test it in `testUnsubscribesNewsletterSubscriber()` by creating an object `NewsletterSubscriber` with a Foundry Factory and then calling this `unsubscribe` method, and then assert that the `NewsletterSubscriber` was correctly updated.

Service that is being tested:

```php
// NewsletterService.php
class NewsletterService
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly EntityManagerInterface           $doctrine,
        private readonly LoggerInterface                  $logger,
        private readonly MailerService                    $mailer,
        private readonly NewsletterSubscriptionRepository $repo,
        private readonly CustomerRepository               $customerRepo
    ) { }
// ...
    public function unsubscribe(string $email): void
    {
        $existing = $this->customerRepo->findOneNewsletterSubscriberByEmail($email);
        if (!$existing) {
            $this->logger->warning('Tried to unsubscribe non-existent subscriber', ['email' => $email]);
            return;
        }

        if (!$existing->isSubscribedToNewsletter()) {
            $this->logger->info('Tried to unsubscribe a non-subscriber', ['email' => $email]);
            return;
        }

        $existing->getNewsletterSubscription()->setUnsubscribedAt(new DateTimeImmutable);
        $this->doctrine->persist($existing);
        $this->doctrine->flush();
    }
}
```

Test:

```php
// NewsletterServiceTest.php
class NewsletterServiceTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    public function testUnsubscribesNewsletterSubscriber(): void
    {
        /** @var Proxy|NewsletterSubscriber $sub */
        $sub = NewsletterSubscriberFixtures::new()->create(
            [
                'email' => 'test@example.com',
                'zipcode' => '12345',
                'newsletterSubscription' => NewsletterSubscriptionFixtures::createOne([
                    'subscribedAt' => new DateTimeImmutable('-1 day'),
                    'unsubscribedAt' => null,
                ]),
            ]
        );

        $this->assertTrue($sub->isSubscribedToNewsletter());

        /** @var NewsletterService $service */
        $service = static::getContainer()->get(NewsletterService::class);
        $service->unsubscribe('test@example.com');

        // I have auto refresh on, but just to be clear:
        $sub->refresh();
        $this->assertNotTrue($sub->isSubscribedToNewsletter()); // fails
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `unsubscribe` method finds the `NewsletterSubscriber` from the repository. (Note: it does find it, I debugged that.) It then sets the `unsubscribedAt` property. After the `unsubscribe` call the `$sub` still has `unsubscribedAt = null`, which shouldn't be the case as it was set by `NewsletterService::unsubscribe` and flushed to database.

**If I write `$em = static::getContainer()->get(EntityManagerInterface::class)`, I can see in the debugger that `unsubscribedAt` is set in `$em->unitOfWork`, but not in `$sub->object`.** I think I can therefore say that this isn't a problem regarding the business logic.

#### Further digging:

If I add a `setUp` method like below

```php
    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        \Zenstruck\Foundry\Test\TestState::bootFoundry((new Configuration())
            ->setManagerRegistry(
                static::getContainer()->get(ManagerRegistry::class)
            )
        );
    }
```

it works. The issue here is that my default locale in `config/packages/test/zenstruck_foundry.yaml` isn't loaded, which I need in my factories. Also, the above `setUp` doesn't seem to be the intended way of doing things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add

```php
// ...
use Zenstruck\Foundry\Test\Factories;
// ...

class NewsletterService extends KernelTestCase
{
    use Factories;
    // ...
}
```

as per [the documentation](https://symfony.com/bundles/ZenstruckFoundryBundle/current/index.html#enable-foundry-in-your-testcase). This trait has a `setUp` function for test-cases involving the kernel (such as `KernelTestCase` and `WebTestCase`).

Comment: Does that answer your question then? If not, please edit your question (and put it in there), not as an answer. If it answered, please mark it as the solution.